# "reduce surface area to imporve security" in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm reading an article, [Introduction to ASP.NET 5](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/aspnet.html) ran into what I couldn't figure out.

> ASP.NET 5 is no longer based on System.Web.dll, but is instead based on a set of granular and well factored NuGet packages allowing you to optimize your app to have just what you need. You can reduce the surface area of your application to improve security, reduce your servicing burden and also to improve performance in a true pay-for-what-you-use model.

What does it mean to reduce the surface area of your application to improve security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"surface area" in security terminology usually refers, roughly, to the size and complexity of the external interface visible to the outside world (and hence to potential attackers).

Reducing the "surface area" means basically reducing the amount and scope of externally-visible interfaces. This, in turn, reduces the number of avenues that an attacker can use to get into your webapp, and also reduces the number of interfaces that need to be checked for security problems.

Comment: As it relates to asp.net 5.  The full .net framework is about 200MB and comprises more than 85,000 classes, anyone one of which could be an attack vector.  The .net core reduces that "surface" by about 90%.